# What is this error that appears when executing my files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Whats the problem ???   I'm working on a bot for discord using JavaScript when executing my files in VS code it works normally but in Repl.it it shows me this error

```
 internal/fs/utils.js:269
        throw err;
        ^
    
    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/runner/Bot/index.js'
        at Object.openSync (fs.js:462:3)
        at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:364:35)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:195:19)
        at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
        at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
        at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
        at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
      errno: -2,
      syscall: 'open',
      code: 'ENOENT',
      path: '/home/runner/Bot/index.js'
    }
```

Comment: Error says it cannot find your index.js file, check your main file entry and adjust your folder tree

Comment: your file is not in the referenced directory, try follow the path that's shown in the code and make sure index.js is in that dir. Or you can try change the page to where ever your index.js is stored